# Switching from website to instant app

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

Say someone taps a link and is shown the appropriate speed bump page prompting the user to open the app or the website and the user chooses to open the website (potentially not knowing why/how they are able to open an app they don't have).

How does that user launch the instant app after choosing to open the website rather than the instant app? I know the user can choose to go to the website after launching the instant app (via the notification) but I don't know how to do the opposite.

As a side note, iOS makes it easy to toggle between a website and app from deep links. Safari shows a small banner that has an "Open app" button if you pull down from the top of the webpage slightly. When you are in the app there is a direct-forward link in the upper-right status bar. This makes it super easy to toggle between the two.

Comment: The instant app dev / pm from Google monitors these questions and they will probably be by shortly with a response to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're in Chrome you can tap on the https/lock and there can be a button showing open instant app. However this doesn't show up on all android versions.

Tested on android 6 showing
Tested on Android 8 not showing

hope this helps

Comment: I had no idea. That was exactly what I was looking for. I was able to find it on my Pixel XL by tapping the info icon in the overflow menu. I hope Google works to improve the visibility of this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Play Console has ["Mobile holdback"](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7381861?hl=en) feature which allows developers to choose the percentage of users who will see the Instant app, so it looks like it cannot be directly controlled by users.